# Select the combobox Items using down Arrow in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a `comboxbox` in one of the columns of the `datagridview` in C#.  However, the cell is focused, and when I try to select the values using the arraw keyz, the values are not selected.

Any idea if I am missing something. Do I need to instantiate any events in order to select the Items through arrow keys.

Attached is the screen capture of my GUI.

[image]

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: i think datagridview gets rebinded on drop select,try breakpoint to chk

Comment: I think the cell might not be in edit mode, so try setting `datagridview.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`, i think this should help

Comment: Thank you so much. That pretty much solved the problem I had. Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `datagridview` should be in `EditMode`, so, you can change the selection of your combo in gridview.